# How to install Ruby 2 and Ruby Gems on Ubuntu box with Ansible

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, ansible

I want to provision *Ubuntu Server* machine with latest *Ruby* and *Ruby Gems* version using *Ansible*.

How do I do this?

Comment: If you downvoting this question could you at least provide the reason in the comments please?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Solution #1: Using APT and Symlinks

I recommend to use this solution if it's OK to install *Ruby 2.0* and *Ruby Gems* globally (for all users). If you want to install another version or isolate it from other users - please see solution #2.

Here's a simple *Ansible* playbook that will install latest *Ruby 2.0* and *Ruby Gems* for you:

### Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr)

```
- name: Latest version of Ruby is installed
  apt: pkg={{ item }} state=latest
  with_items:
    - ruby2.0
    - ruby2.0-dev

- name: Symlink exists for Ruby 2.0
  file: src=/usr/bin/ruby2.0 dest=/usr/local/bin/ruby state=link

- name: Symlink exists for Ruby Gems 2.0
  file: src=/usr/bin/gem2.0 dest=/usr/local/bin/gem state=link
```

### Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander)

```
- name: Latest version of Ruby is installed
  apt: pkg={{ item }} state=latest
  with_items:
    - ruby2.0
    - ruby2.0-dev

- name: Making Ruby 2.0 the default one
  command: update-alternatives --set ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.0

- name: Making Gem 2.0 the default one
  command: update-alternatives --set gem /usr/bin/gem2.0
```

---

Provided playbooks must be executed with `sudo: yes` for obvious reasons.

## Solution #2: Using RVM

*RVM is installing ruby and it's gems locally for current user. So it leads to a problems in multi-user environment. In my use-case it was not working correctly for some reason. So I would recommend to stick to the first solution if possible. Although, if you know what you are doing and understand the complications here goes the RVM solution.*

I suggest to create a simple shell script to install current version of Ruby and Ruby Gems with [RVM](http://rvm.io/) and invoke it later on a provisioned machine.

Here's the *Bash* script:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Checking if RVM is installed
if ! [ -d "~/.rvm" ]; then
    echo "Installing RVM..."
    \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
    source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
    echo "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc
else
    echo "Updating RVM..."
    rvm get stable
fi;

echo -n "RVM version is: "
rvm --version

echo "Installing Ruby..."
rvm install ruby

echo "Making installed Ruby the default one..."
rvm use ruby --default

echo "Installing latest version of Ruby Gems..."
rvm rubygems current
```

This script will install *RVM* (or update it to a latest stable version if it's already installed) and it will install latest stable versions of *Ruby* and *Ruby Gems*.

And here's the playbook to copy provided script to the provisioning machine and invoke it:

```
- file: path=~/provision/ruby state=directory
- copy: src=../../files/ruby/install.sh dest=~/provision/ruby/install.sh mode=775

- name: Latest Ruby is installed
  shell: /usr/bin/env bash ~/provision/ruby/install.sh
```

Just place your script near the Ansible's playbook and update the paths.

I hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

There's now an official Ruby/RVM playbook: https://github.com/rvm/rvm1-ansible

To install: `ansible-galaxy install rvm_io.rvm1-ruby -p ROLES_PATH`

Example playbook:

```
---

- name: Configure servers with ruby support
  hosts: all
  roles:
    - { role: rvm_io.rvm1-ruby, tags: ruby, become: True }
```